# Build Docker image locally that requires NuGet authentication

Tags: docker, nuget, azure-pipelines

When building a Docker image in an Azure DevOps pipeline that requires access to a private NuGet feed you need to run the `NuGetAuthenticate` task first in order to get an access token.

What is the local equivalent of this? i.e. I fetch a token, plug it into `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` and pass it as args when running the Docker build?

Comment: isnt enough with the PAT in nuget.config file ?

Comment: How do you get a PAT? How do I run equivalent of `NuGetAuthenticate` locally?

Answer (score 3):

> I fetch a token, plug it into VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS and pass it as args when running the Docker build?

Yes，a `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` environment variable is used to supply an access token.

Sample dockfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
COPY ./nuget.config .
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://fabrikam.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyGreatFeed/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app/
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

Before running docker build, first populate the `FEED_ACCESSTOKEN` environment variable with a `personal access token`. Then, this Dockerfile would be built using this command:

```
docker build --build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN .
```

You can check the doc "[Using the Azure Artifact Credential Provider](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-the-azure-artifact-credential-provider)" for the detail setting.

Or you can directly add the credential in `nuget.config`,please check doc M[anaging NuGet Credentials in Docker Scenarios](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#managing-nuget-credentials-in-docker-scenarios) for the details.

On Azure DevOps, please make sure the account doesn't have Multi factor authentication(MFA) required, on local machine, you need to follow the popup message to login.